# Search for closes index on SQL table

Tags: sql, amazon-dynamodb

I have a hypothetical SQL table "EVENTS", with two columns, a UUID index column, and a DateTime column,
The table is populated with values ranging from `1900-01-01` to today, it is not ordered, there are numerous dates missing.

The query that I have to run is basically 'retrieve all events that happened at the requested date (start to the end of the day) or the closest previous date'

If I were looking for all events in a day that I know that exists in the database it would be something as simple as:

```
SELECT * FROM Events e
WHERE
e.date BETWEEN $START_OF_DAY AND $END_OF_DAY;
```

But if that date doesn't exist I must retrieve the latest date up to the requested date.

Comment: I would go with a table value function and check if events exist in the day, and then return day or newest

Comment: You state that "If I were looking for a single event in a day that I know that exists in the database it would be something as simple as" but your query potentially returns multiple events. It doesn't clear if you are looking for multiple events or a single event

Comment: Yes, it would, and thats the correct assumption, I just wasant able to properly communicate that, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: And if there are no events from the requested day? Do you want a single event or multiple events from the preceding day?

Comment: The query is like "get all events that happened in the same specific, if no events are in that day return the latest day before that which has events"

Comment: What DB / SQL engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab current day, but if no records found, will return all records from the nearest previous day with records.
So in my sample data, Jan 2 returns 3 events dated Jan 1

### SQL Server Solution

```
DECLARE @Input DATE = '2022-01-02' /*Try Jan 1,2,3, or 4*/
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Event

CREATE TABLE #Event (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),EventDateTime DATETIME)
INSERT INTO #Event
VALUES 
('2022-01-01 08:00')
,('2022-01-01 09:00')
,('2022-01-01 10:00')
,('2022-01-03 12:00')

SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES *
FROM #Event AS A
CROSS APPLY (SELECT EventDate = CAST(EventDateTime AS DATE)) AS B
WHERE B.EventDate <= @Input
ORDER BY B.EventDate DESC
```

SQL Fiddle wasn't letting me create a variable, but here's a the code conceptually for a more efficient version for MySQL. It grabs the desired date range in the first query, then uses it to filter in the second query. I think it should perform far better than the accepted answer assuming you have an index on EventDateTime

```
CREATE TABLE Event (
ID MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
,EventDateTime DATETIME
,PRIMARY KEY (ID));

INSERT INTO Event (EventDateTime)
VALUES 
('2022-01-01 08:00')
,('2022-01-01 09:00')
,('2022-01-01 10:00')
,('2022-01-03 12:00');


/*Need to save these off to variables to use in later query*/
SELECT TIMESTAMP(CAST(EventDateTime AS DATE)) AS StartRange
  ,TIMESTAMP(CAST(EventDateTime AS DATE)) + INTERVAL 1 DAY AS EndRange
FROM Event
WHERE EventDateTime < DATE_ADD('2022-01-04' /*Input*/,INTERVAL 1 DAY)
ORDER BY EventDateTime DESC
LIMIT 1;

SELECT *
FROM Event
WHERE EventDateTime >= StartRange
AND EventDateTime < EndRange
```

Comment: This solution is interesting, but I'm unable to test a solution that is dependent on sql-server-specific functionality.

Comment: Wasn't sure your DBMS, but thought it might help others understand the problem better. Added an outline of a MySQL approach that I believe should perform better than the accepted answer

Comment: Im sorry, my DB is actually DynamoDB, (not possible to solve it without a partition scan), I'm looking for other ways to solve the problem, so I tried to solve it using sqlite/mysql/postgresql but still couldnt find better ways other than making multiple queries.

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the most recent date, and do a self join. Although I'm using MYSQL, I believe this is the most generic workaround

```sql
CREATE TABLE d0207Event (ID INT ,EventDateTime DATETIME)

INSERT INTO d0207Event
VALUES 
(1,'2022-01-01 08:00')
,(2,'2022-01-01 09:00')
,(3,'2022-01-01 10:00')
,(4,'2022-01-03 12:00')

INSERT INTO d0207Event
VALUES 
(5, '2021-12-12 08:00');

select t1.*
  from d0207Event t1,
  (
    select min(t1.dat) mindat
      from (
        select t1.*,
               DATEDIFF('2022-01-02', cast(t1.EventDateTime as date)) dat
          from d0207Event t1
    ) t1
     where t1.dat >= 0
 ) t2
 where DATEDIFF('2022-01-02', cast(t1.EventDateTime as date)) = t2.mindat
;
```

There are also many advanced syntaxes that can solve this problem better, depending on which DB you use and your specific application scenario

It seems that you can also choose a database with more syntax, then using an analytic function usually solves the efficiency problem well, since the EVENT table only needs to be queried once.

```sql
CREATE TABLE Event (
ID MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
,EventDateTime DATETIME
,PRIMARY KEY (ID));

INSERT INTO Event (EventDateTime)
VALUES 
('2022-01-01 08:00')
,('2022-01-01 09:00')
,('2022-01-01 10:00')
,('2022-01-03 12:00');

select *
  from (
    select t1.*,
           first_value(cast(t1.EventDateTime as date)) 
                over(order by cast(t1.EventDateTime as date) desc) fv
      from event t1
     where cast(t1.EventDateTime as date) <= '2022-01-03'
) t1
 where cast(t1.EventDateTime as date) = fv
```

Creating a functional index `cast(t1.EventDateTime as date)`, or creating a virtual column directly can make the query easier, otherwise using date_add() is a good way

Comment: This is heavy in memory, but helps me find a way to solve it, thanks :)